# Add class every third <li> throug Php

Tags: php, wordpress

I get dynamic post in WordPress. But I want to add class after every third `<li>`.

Like this.

```
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li class="last_child"></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li class="last_child"></li>
```

Comment: Why not use CSS' `nth-child`?

Comment: He does not specify that this is for use with CSS. But if it is, I agree that this would be the best solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're creating them via for-loop, you can just check on the index. Something like this:

```
for ($i=0; $i<$num_lis; $i++) {
    echo '<li'.($i % 3 == 2 ? ' class="last_child"' : '').'></li>';
}
```

Or if you prefer not to use ternary notation:

```
for ($i=0; $i<$num_list; $i++) {
    if ($i % 3 == 2) {
         echo '<li class="last_child"></li>';
    } else {
         echo '<li></li>';
    }
}
```

But as j08691 comments, you're probably better off simply selecting every third `li` in whatever it is that you have using the `last_child` class, i.e. `nth-child` for CSS, e.g.

```
li:nth-child(3n) {
 styles
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use CSS:

```
li:nth-child(3n) { 
    /* Your styles here */
}
```

Also as an option, Wordpress has built in jQuery, so you can also use **[.addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/)**:

```
$("ul li:nth-child(3n)").addClass("last_child");
```

Comment: Because the class might not be for use with CSS, the jQuery actually gives the element the class.